# how much does it cost to move my car from US to Netherlands?

Tags: netherlands

I have recently purchased a car in US and I am moving to Netherlands to work there.

I have read somewhere that I can import my car to Netherlands as a part of my households exempt from tax.

But how much does it cost to ship the car to Netherlands?

Comment: A cursory internet search suggests something around $2000 to $4000.  But be sure that you'll want to have it there.  If you're going to be in central Amsterdam, for example, you may have to wait months before you can get a parking permit.

Comment: You don’t state what make and model of car but you might also want to check urban access regulations https://urbanaccessregulations.eu/countries-mainmenu-147/netherlands-mainmenu-88 for the area of the Netherlands you’ll be moving to.

Comment: Europe in general (and the Netherlands in particular) are extremely well thought-out for people without their own cars. Because space is very tight (see @phoog's comment above about parking permits) and public transport (trains, trams, buses) is ubiquitous and inexpensive, most people ride bikes and many don't have cars at all. I imagine you're attached to your new purchase, but you should think twice or thrice about taking a car with you. It will be of limited use and very expensive to keep. Were I you, I'd make a different decision.

Comment: @David on the other hand, the train network is far less dense outside the randstad, so a car is much more useful, and even within it there are lots of people who commute by car.  It really depends on where you're living and working.

Comment: @Traveller I'm gonna work in Amsterdam and reside somewhere outside Amsterdam within 30 minutes driving distance. My car is an Hyundai Elantra.

Comment: @phoog aren't there enough free/paid parking lots or structures available in Amsterdam?

Comment: Free parking? In a city centre??? https://www.amsterdam.info/parking/

Comment: @Polymorphic indoor parking is too expensive for most people to afford.  I knew a few people who parked their cars out in the suburbs while they were waiting for a permit.  It was fairly inconvenient, but if you live in the center the best use for your car is to travel to other cities, so it does make sense.

Comment: But the OP said he was going to live out and commute to the center. It might well be more reasonable for him to commute to a rail station and then take the train in, rather than struggling to park in the center every work day.

Comment: @Polymorphic You should also find out what it'll take to legalize your US car in the Netherlands, i.e., what must be done (if anything) to register and insure it there as a Netherlands vehicle.

Comment: @David Is there a website to find out wheather my car can be legalized in Netherlands or not. It's a Hyundai Elantra 2.0

Comment: I don't know, I haven't searched this issue for US > NL. It is clear from discussions here and on other websites that registering cars in countries for which they were not originally intended is frequently a great deal of trouble and expense, and sometimes impossible. You should not assume it'd be easy or quick. For a reality check between two countries with the same language and similar cultures who share car manufacturing facilities (which you'd think would help), read this: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11169/how-do-i-buy-and-import-a-car-from-canada-to-the-us

Comment: Thanks all for sharing invaluable information. I guess it's better to leave the car in US to a friend and after a couple of months living in Netherlands and completing my research, then make the best decision. :)

Comment: @Polymorphic I think that's prudent, and very sensible.